# Force strings and pointers into flash when using X-macro expansion

Tags: c, embedded, x-macros

I thought I understood X-macros pretty well but this is really stumping me. I defined the following code:

```
#define FOR_DESCR_STRINGS(apply) \
    apply(LANGUAGE_ID_STRING, "\0x04\0x03\0x09\0x04")  \
    apply(MANUFACTURER_STRING, "Quest Engineering & Development, Inc.") \
    apply(PRODUCT_STRING, "PowerExpander Eq10E") \
    apply(SERIAL_NUMBER_STRING, "\0x00")              \
    apply(MS_OS_COMPAT_STRING "MSFT100\0xFF")

#define SELECT_DESCR_STRING_ID(a, b) a,
#define SELECT_DESCR_STRING(a, b) b
#define SELECT_DESCR_STRING_PTR(a, b) b,

enum
{
     FOR_DESCR_STRINGS(SELECT_DESCR_STRING_ID)
     DESCR_STRING_CNT
};

const uint8_t  DESCR_STRINGS[][] = /* Array of Descriptor Strings */
    {FOR_DESCR_STRINGS(SELECT_DESCR_STRING)};  

const uint8_t* DESCR_STRING_PTRS[] = /* Array of Descriptor String Ptrs */
    {FOR_DESCR_STRINGS(SELECT_DESCR_STRING_PTR)};
```

I wanted the strings and pointers to go into flash but what I am ending up with is .rodata where the pointers and strings are being copied to RAM during the C startup code.  Is there anyway to do what I want to do here (define multiple strings and define pointer array to strings) so they stay in flash and are not copied to RAM while still using X-macros? 
Thanks,

Comment: I would assume, the way you create your arrays (X-Macros or not) is unrelated to why they end in RAM and not in flash. It is quite specific to OS, system, Flash type, loading strategies and other settings, what you will eventually end up with. For example, some FLASH memories cannot be randomly adressed and the loader loads the whole image to RAM on startup. More examples: Some FLASH have slower access speed as RAM on some systems, and thus, the system specific tools make according trade off decisions... Tell us more about what you deal with and we might have ideas.

Comment: This has nothing to do with X-macros obviously.

Comment: OK, then maybe just a misunderstanding of C. I think maybe I need to emulate what I do without X-macros more fully.  Thanks,

Answer (score -1):

Your problem lies less with macro expansion or C as it does with the linker and the scatter gather/linker descriptor file, and maybe with your underlying hardware.

`const` data will almost always be directed towards `.rodata`, which is placed in the memory map by the linker descriptor file, which also (sort of...and probably very indirectly) specifies things that need to be initialized by the startup library or not.

You might be able to use a `#pragma` or `__attribute__()` to change the section name from `.rodata` to `.text`, but these sort of things are notoriously fickle, brittle, and very vendor specific.   GNU does it differently than Keil, or IAR, or GHS, and sometimes the mechanisms and undocumented features (like this where you poke at it until it works for you) change from version to version.

Even if you could, you may find out that your USB controller simply cannot access the flash, necessitating you expand it into SRAM anyways.

Comment: Actually the USB controller can access the flash.  If I do this discretely to force it into flash I need to do this `const uint8_t PRODUCT_STRING[]         = {"PowerExpander Eq10E"};`   Then I need to reference the pointer in a uint32_t array.  The enum is easy.  I think I need to emulate this more directly with my x-macro expansion.  Thanks for your input.